# some css character codes (\25b6 and \25c0) not aligning in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using CSS character codes to show two triangles for previous and next and they are laid out via flexbox. I'm noticing a strange vertical alignment issue.

Here is the first example. The left and right pointing arrows don't align.

```css
div {
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: center;
}
.some::before {
  content: "\25c0";
}
.more::after {
  content: "\25b6";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="some">
    <a><span>some text</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="other">
    Other Text
  </div>
  <div class="more">
    <a><span>some more text</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I change the arrows to the same CSS character they do align

```css
div {
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: center;
}
.some::before {
  content: "\25b6";
}
.more::after {
  content: "\25b6";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="some">
    <a><span>some text</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="other">
    Other Text
  </div>
  <div class="more">
    <a><span>some more text</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using flex-direction: column; and align-content with no luck. In fact with align-content the invert alignment occurred where the other arrow was misaligned.

adding a link to a JSFiddle cause it shows up very obviously there: https://jsfiddle.net/L2fgcpyv/2/

Comment: The two unicode triangles are different sizes. The black left pointing triangle is `16x18` where the right pointing triangle is `14.08x18`.

Comment: Thanks. kind of annoying. I would expected them to be the same size...

Comment: [They appear to be in a proper vertical alignment for me (on Chrome).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kImRx.png) The same on jsfiddle. Different glyph width shouldn't have an affect on vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Since those two triangles are differently sized. I found that are the same and are much more consistent across browsers

https://unicode-table.com/en/25C4/

https://unicode-table.com/en/25BA/